# how I create a new whole list by dividing a list of tuples in python

Tags: python, list, data-structures, tuples

i have a list like this:

```
[[(62, 57),
  (59, 23),
  (49, 5),
  (138, 10),
  (37, 52),
  (145, 3),
  (13, -1),
  (30, 5),
  (15, 4)],
 [(31, 1),
  (74, 0),
  (85, 8),
  (85, 25),
  (45, 4),
  (38, 0),
  (37, 0),
  (16, 0),
  (102, -1)]]
```

And I need to create another list from the division by the numbers between parentesis and i have no clue how to do it.
I need something like this:
`[1.08, 2.56, 9.8, and so on]`
ps. if one of the numbers is 0 filter it.

Comment: This is a perfect use for a list comprehension.

Comment: `list(starmap(truediv, lst))` Imports: [`truediv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truediv), [`starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap). Or using list comprehension: `[a / b for a, b in lst if b]`

Comment: Are you saying you don't have any idea how to divide two numbers that are present in a tuple?

Comment: You have nested lists, so you'll need nested list comprehensions.

Comment: @enke The question says he wants to skip them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
my_list = [[(62, 57), (59, 23), (49, 5), (138, 10), (37, 52), (145, 3), (13, -1), (30, 5), (15, 4)],
           [(31, 1), (74, 0), (85, 8), (85, 25), (45, 4), (38, 0), (37, 0), (16, 0), (102, -1)]]

[[a/b for a,b in l if b] for l in my_list]
```

Output:

```
[[1.087719298245614, 2.5652173913043477, 9.8, 13.8, 0.7115384615384616, 48.333333333333336, -13.0, 6.0, 3.75],
 [31.0, 10.625, 3.4, 11.25, -102.0]]
```

*NB. if you want to ensure that both numbers are non zero, use `if a and b`*